# How to reverse the SingleLinkedList in the Java?

Tags: java

Hi I want to print the `SingleLinkedList` in reverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

static void Collections.reverse(List list):
http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html

Comment: +1: You might want to give the link for Java 6 instead of an old version. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure that this is a `List`. Plus even if it is, if it's a single linked list, the `swap()` in reverse will be really time consuming.

Answer (score 0):

See `Collections.reverse` ([JavaDoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverse%28java.util.List%29))

Answer (score 0):

I don't know for "The SingleLinkedList" class (is it even a `List` implementation ?) but if it works as its name states, the best way (more effective one) would be to go through the data structure and put every element in a stack. Then simply read the stack.

Answer (score 0):

public print(Element el) {
  if (el.next!=null)
    print(el.next);
  System.out.print(el.value+" ");
}

Basicaly its puting it in (call) stack an reading it (as someone else sugested). Nonrecursive version using explicit stack is usualy faster, does not risk StackOverflowException and takes longer to write.